# For loop isn't running C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I am writing a piece of code to make two LED lights blink in a specific sequential order.

**my code**

```
int main()
{
    int blue = 3;
    int green = 4;
    int time = 1;
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;

    greenLED = 1;
    blueLED = 1;
    wait(1);

    for(time; time<green*blue; time++)
    {
        if (time == green*i)
        {
            blueLED = 1;
            i=i+1;
        }
        if(time == blue*j)
        {
            greenLED = 1;
            j=j+1;
        }
        wait(1);
    }
}
```

My problem is that it says my for loop has no effect. I am assuming that it means my for loop is not running because the expression for my for loop doesn't make sense or isn't picking up any of the variables I have? Can someone please help me out and tell me why?

cheers

Comment: Remove the semicolon at `time++;`.

Comment: blueLED and greenLED are not declared before they are initialized with value 1, so can you check your code once and do possible required changes.

Comment: and in both conditions inside for loop you are assigning same value to both blueLED and greenLED which they already have, doesn't make any sense

Comment: "wait()" is undeclared

Comment: Just removed the semicolon and compiled my code. There were no error messages that came back after compiling my code but this time the two LEDs still did not do anything so I assume the for loop is still not running. Is there anything else you could suggest for me to change, add or remove?

Comment: The blueLED and greenLED are declared before this code, I didnt add it in as it wasnt showing in the code box for some reason

Comment: I'll try add it in this comment section

Comment: This is what is written for my code before the code that is shown above '#include <iostream>
#include "mbed.h"

using namespace std;
DigitalOut greenLED(PA_5);
DigitalOut blueLED(PA_7);'

Comment: Instead of posting essential information in the comments, please edit the question. (And please spend some time making the question as coherent as possible, to make it easy for folks to help you.)

Comment: @TeMatauOTeRangiAllen What makes you think the loop is not running? Did you actually verify that via debugging? The loop is merely setting variables, but where is the code that actually uses those variables to update the LEDs?

Comment: @Remylebeau because when the code is sent to run the LEDs it does and runs the LEDs as stated in this part of the code here `greenLED = 1;
    blueLED = 1;
    wait(1);` but when the code gets to the for loop it doesn't do anything

Comment: Make an [mre] which allows to see how `blueLED = 1;` has an effect on the hardware. I am pretty sure that I know what is behind that, but you need to make that visible in your shown code. If any long hardware-related header is involved, make sure to only put the relevant part into your shown code.

Comment: Please try to describe how your loop works in English prose, that way you might either help us to understand or help yourself to find the logical error.

Comment: okay well, `blueLED = 1` and `greenLED = 1` turns the LED on as "1 = high" to turn the LEDs off you would see the code read 'blueLED = 0' as "0 = low"

Comment: I will add the logic or my code to the main question with a photo

Comment: The reason for the warning is the `for (time;time<green*blue; time++)`.     That first usage of `time` has no effect.      Change the loop to `for (  ;time<green*blue; time++)` - i.e. remove the part that does nothing - and the compiler should stop warning you (about that, at least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is what you wanted

```
int main()
{

    int blue = 3;
    int green = 4;
    int time = 1;
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;

    int greenLED = 1;
    int blueLED = 1;

    for(time; time<green*blue; time++)
    {
        blueLED=0;
        greenLED=0;
        printf("for loop start\n");
        if (time == green*i)
        {
            printf("if1\n");
            blueLED = 1;
            i=i+1;
        }
        if(time == blue*j)
        {
            printf("if2\n");
            greenLED = 1;
            j=j+1;
        }
        printf("endforloop\n");
        printf("%d\n",greenLED);
        printf("%d\n",blueLED);

    }


}
```

as you see the for loop is running

Comment: It's okay I realized what through explaining my code to you. Thank you!!

Comment: @outeh The loop shown is re-declaring the LED variables, shadowing the ones that are declared above the loop.